# Export a CC Library as a list of vector files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, adobe-creative-suite

I would like to export a CC Library composed of vector graphics as vector files.

I am only able to export it as a .cclib file from the Creative Cloud app or from the Adobe website.

I would like to export as a folder containing the original source files in either .ai or .indd format or .svg works too.

**How does one export their CC Libraries assets locally into files?**

Comment: Disclosure: . I don't use the CC libraries here.. not a fan of the CC cloud storage. ---- I'd *guess* that it's very similar to symbols... One *can't* export/save individual symbols to their own file. They have to be dragged to the artboard (sometimes breaking the link) and then saved. InDesign's (local) libraries don't offer any saving ability either. I'd wager this isn't possible without at least scripting to place, save, delete, and then repeat.

Comment: I see. Not a fan either but the cloud race must go on I guess, even if it creates more problems than it solves